# handle onValueChange of Child Component in Parent Component in React native

Tags: react-native, components, state, reusability, modularity

I am modulating my Big component into small chunks. in Parent Component i've a lot of Switch and CheckbBox components.

Here it is

**ParentComponent.js**

```
<View style={styles.sliderContainer}>
                            <Text style={styles.sliderLabel}>Diettags:</Text>
                            <CheckBoxComponent label={'Sugarfree'} availableItems={13}/>
                            <CheckBoxComponent label={'Youth'} availableItems={11}/>
                            <CheckBoxComponent label={'Metabolites'} availableItems={10}/>
                            <CheckBoxComponent label={'Fodmap'} availableItems={7}/>
                        </View>
```

**CheckBoxCompoenent.js**

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'
import {Text, View, CheckBox, Switch, Platform,StyleSheet} from "react-native";
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'


class CheckBoxComponent extends Component {

    state={
        checked: true
    };

    render() {
        const { label,handleToggle,availableItems} = this.props;
        const {checked} = this.state;
        return (
            Platform.OS === 'ios' ?
                <View style={styles.mainContainer}>
                    <Text style={styles.label}>{`${label}(${availableItems})`}</Text>
                    <Switch value={checked}/>
                </View> :
                <View style={styles.mainContainer}>
                    <Text style={styles.label}>{`${label}(${availableItems})`}</Text>
                    <CheckBox value={checked} />
                </View>
        )


    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
   mainContainer: {
       flex: 1,
       justifyContent: 'space-between',
       alignItems: 'center',
       flexDirection: 'row',
       marginLeft: 20,
       marginRight: 20,
       marginTop: 10
   },
   label: {
       fontSize: 16,
   }
});

CheckBoxComponent.proptype = {
    label: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    handleToggle: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    availableItems: PropTypes.string
};

export default CheckBoxComponent
```

**Now what i want**

> I want to handle **onValueChange of Switch and Checkbox** in my Parent Component

I have tried out all ways available on stackoverflow but but nothing helped me.

Someone please guide me through code how to solve this problem. ?

Thank you so much

Comment: you can use checkboxes for both OS using react-native-elements

Comment: if you are not making hooks ! then its simple use pass function as prop! to child component to handle the state change! here lemme put an example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I am looking at is that you need to provide the function in child component and the state value using props.

//parent component:

```
 <View style={styles.sliderContainer}>
                    <Text style={styles.sliderLabel}>Diettags:</Text>
                    <CheckBoxComponent label={'Sugarfree'} availableItems={13} checked={this.state.checked} onValueChange={this.handleValueChange} />
                    <CheckBoxComponent label={'Youth'} availableItems={11}/>
                    <CheckBoxComponent label={'Metabolites'} availableItems={10}/>
                    <CheckBoxComponent label={'Fodmap'} availableItems={7}/>
                </View>
```

child component do this:

```
 const { label,handleToggle,availableItems,checked} = this.props;
    return (
        Platform.OS === 'ios' ?
            <View style={styles.mainContainer}>
                <Text style={styles.label}>{`${label}`} <Text style={{color: 'red'}}>({availableItems})</Text></Text>
                <Switch value={checked} onValueChange={(text) => this.props.onValueChange(text)}/>
            </View> :
            <View style={styles.mainContainer}>
                <Text style={styles.label}>{`${label}(${availableItems})`}</Text>
                <CheckBox value={checked} />
            </View>
    )


}
```

the above shall get you going and the rest is on you! you can finish it by using the good maping technique as been told by the first answer here by @auticcat.

Answer (score 1):

In this case i would suggest to use a map and array to render the checkboxes. It would become like this:

```
constructor(props){ 
    super(props)
    this.state={
    checkBoxesArray:[{label: "Sugarfree",avaiableItems:13}, {label: "Youth",avaiableItems:11}, {label: "Metabolites",avaiableItems:10}, {label: "Fodmap",avaiableItems:7}]
    }
}
```

Then in your render:

```
<View style={styles.sliderContainer}>
    <Text style={styles.sliderLabel}>Diettags:</Text>
    {this.checkBoxesArray.map((item, index) => <CheckBoxComponent label={'item.label'} availableItems={item.avaiableItems} onValueChange={this.onValueChange} checkBoxIndex={index}/>
)
</View>
```

Then, in the child, when you need to call onValueChange you simply call the function you passed from parent doing:

```
onPress={()=> this.props.onValueChange(this.props.checkBoxIndex)}
```

At end, in your parent you will need a function to handle it, like:

```
onValueChange= (index) =>{
//do what you need
}
```